# Nested loops - Why do the loops include the previous evaluation?

Tags: perl, nested-loops, repeat

My intention is to count the number of words in List 2 that contain each of the letters in List 1.
When I run the code, the first count is fine; however, the subsequent counts are added to the previous ones, such that the final count is the sum of all the counts, not the count of how many "words" contain an "F", as I want it to be.
Where am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
use warnings; use strict;


my $count=0;
my @list1  = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
my @list2 = ("AXE", "DOG", "CAT", "FOOD", "TRANCE");

for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@list1); $i++){ 
    for (my $j=0; $j<scalar(@list2); $j++){
        my $word = $list2[$j];  
        my $letter = $list1[$i];

        if ($word =~ /$letter/){
            $count++;
        }
    }   
    print "$count \n";
}
```

All the help appreciated.

Comment: `for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@list1); $i++)` is a complicated way of writing `for my $i (0..$#list1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your spec correctly, you just want to move the count declaration/initialization into the outer `for` loop:

```
for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < scalar(@list1) ; $i++ ) {
    my $count = 0;
```

This resets the count for each letter.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said above, you just need to reset the counter variable in order to get the correct result.

However, you can really simplify the code by making use of grep rather than nesting loops.  Here's how I might do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @list1 = qw( A B C D E F );
my @list2 = qw( AXE DOG CAT FOOD TRANCE );

# Iterate over the letter array, using grep to count how many times 
# it shows up in each word, and then store that result to a hash
my %result;
for my $letter ( @list1 ) {
    my $count = grep { $_ =~ /$letter/ } @list2;
    $result{$letter} = $count;
}

# Now print out all of the results
print "Number of words found for each letter:\n";
for ( sort keys %result ) {
    print "$_: $result{$_}\n";
}
```

This gives me the following result based on your test data:

```
Number of words found for each letter:
A: 3
B: 0
C: 2
D: 2
E: 2
F: 1
```